# Can't post messages in Slack mobile website

Tags: slack

I log into Slack from my mobile phone web browser (Chrome 48 on Android 5.1), and I see:

> Hey there !
>   Account settings
>   Notification settings
>   Team directory
>   Customize settings
>   Statistics

The only way I can see channels is by clicking the menu button at the top, which brings this menu:

> signed in as
>   Home
>   Account & Profile
>   Configure Apps
>   Message Archives
>   Files
>   Team Directory
>   Statistics
>   Customize
>   Team Settings

And then clicking "Message Archives", which lets me see others' messages but still doesn't have a way to post messages.

Is there another way to do this?

Comment: (This would probably be better off at [android.se].)

Answer (score 3):

From what I can see, you cannot post messages on Slack from the mobile web site. Even if you request the desktop version of the site there does not appear a way to post messages.

You'll need to install the [Slack](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.Slack) app.

Comment: +1 thanks, but...huh?? How can they make the desktop version of their site show differently on my phone than on my desktop? Is it actually a problem with my phone browser then?

Comment: @krubo: There's a number of ways. The agent-string is one. Looking at the size of the browser is another. I don't think it's a problem with your browser; it works that way for me, too. The Slack app is pretty lightweight; it's worth getting.

Answer (score 1):

Use Slack web on mobile.

Open Chrome > click on the 3 dots menu on the right > click on "Desktop Site" check box > enter message > hit enter button on mobile.

The above is working for me.

Comment: Hey, that's great! I did same with Firefox and it works nice. And I receive notifications. The option is called "Request desktop site". Thanks a lot!